# JQuery Hide Function Doesn't work in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

I have created the following code to show and hide divs. This shows one div at a time and hides the others. This works on all browsers except Safari.

HTML

```
<div class="buttons">
    <a class="button" id="showdiv1">Div 1</a>
    <a class="button" id="showdiv2">Div 2</a>
    <a class="button" id="showdiv3">Div 3</a>
    <a class="button" id="showdiv4">Div 4</a>
</div>
<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">2</div>
<div id="div3" style="display:none;">3</div>
<div id="div4" style="display:none;">4</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('#showdiv1').click( function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div1').show();
});
$('#showdiv2').click( function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div2').show();
});
$('#showdiv3').click( function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div3').show();
});
$('#showdiv4').click( function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div4').show();
});​
```

I am an absolute beginner and thought that Jquery would be the most elegant solution to showing multiple divs and it is! Except for Safari!

Any help would be great-fully received!

Comment: Works for me with Safari 5.1.5: http://jsbin.com/iqexec

Comment: And works for me too, Safari 5.1.5
http://jsfiddle.net/RMhkW/

Comment: The code you've quoted in the question has an invalid character right at the end. It's a U+200B character. If I actually copy and paste your code, it fails in every browser I've tried it in: http://jsbin.com/ojezin In my earlier version, I assumed I'd somehow introduced that character and deleted it, but apparently not.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It is the invisible character in the code! I deleted the last section of the code and typed it manually and the code now works. This character is not visible and cannot be searched for in (don't shout but it works for me) Dreamweaver!

Comment: @user1335857: Good deal! I've posted that as an answer. Well done using copy and paste when writing your question -- you'd be surprised how many people retype their code, and so this kind of thing doens't get figured out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume the problem with Safari is because it does not raise a `click` event on `a` elements which have no `href` attribute.

Also, your code can be simplified. Try this instead:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <a class="button" id="showdiv1" href="#div1">Div 1</a>
    <a class="button" id="showdiv2" href="#div2">Div 2</a>
    <a class="button" id="showdiv3" href="#div3">Div 3</a>
    <a class="button" id="showdiv4" href="#div4">Div 4</a>
</div>
<div id="div1" class="child">1</div>
<div id="div2" class="child" style="display:none;">2</div>
<div id="div3" class="child" style="display:none;">3</div>
<div id="div4" class="child" style="display:none;">4</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".child").hide();
    $($(this).attr("href")).show();
});
```

Notice the use of classes to group elements together so that you don't have so much code repetition.

Comment: jQuery running on Safari has no problem with attribute starts-with selectors. Nice shortening of the code, though. :-)

Comment: Yeah - I did think that was the case, it was as I was typing that I realised the `a` elements didn't have hrefs. I'll edit that out.

Comment: I have to agree with T.J. I was looking for elegant and this certainly is, although this still does not work. :-(

Comment: What version of Safari are you testing with?

Answer (score 0):

The code you've quoted in the question has an invalid character right at the end. It's a U+200B character right after the final `;`. If I actually copy and paste your code, it fails in every browser I've tried it in: http://jsbin.com/ojezin At first when building a test case at this end (see my comment on the question), I thought I'd somehow introduced that character and so I just deleted it. But then I got to thinking and did another copy and paste, and lo, the character was there.